# City filter does not filter jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Restricting searches on Careers does not appear to restrict to the requested geographic area like it used to.  I have attempted to search for the city by name and ZIP code, as well as with and without keywords.

The keywords filter works fine, whether or not I provide a location.

These filters worked the last time I used the search feature on the site about a week ago.

Here are two screenshots showing my attempting searches:

[image: Location restricted search with no keywords showing no filtering]

[image: Location restricted search with keywords showing filtering by keywords only]

In case it helps narrow it down, the XHR request for this search went to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=react&location=80112&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&ajax=1` which looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Curious, do you have any of the check marks in that section ticked? : Allows Remote - 
Offers Relocation - 
Offers Visa Sponsorship

Comment: @Catija: Nope.  All checkboxes are cleared.

Comment: That's odd. Works fine for me. Results for zip code 80112 gives only 28 hits. :  `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=80112&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles`

Comment: Possibly related: I got an automatic e-mail last night about jobs within 60 miles of my city, which I had previously opted in for, but the jobs listed were all over the world (by which I mean mostly nowhere near me).

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271463/subscription-bug-ignores-allows-remote-work-filter   This bug seems to affect all filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Conspicuous Compiler. I've just deployed a fix to job search that should make your results a lot better. Sorry for the bug.