# Subscription Bug: Emails including jobs that do not match defined filters

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search, subscription

A few days ago, many users have started receiving emails from job subscriptions that contain jobs that do not match the filters defined for the subscription.

The examples below show screen-grabs from a couple of emails where is bug has manifested itself.

The first shows a subscription for jobs that allow remote working:
[image]

When you look at any of the jobs from the above email, they do not allow remote working:
[image]

The second example shows jobs confined to a specific geographic area, however, the jobs included within the email are clearly outside of the geographic area defined:
[image]

Furthermore, performing a search on the Stack Overflow Careers site for C# jobs within 50 miles of London, UK also give erroneous results:
[image]

It seems that there's a bug with the job search that's ignoring all search criteria.

Comment: I started getting the same thing. I just came here to report it, actually. As with your case, it still says "jobs allowing remote work" at the top of the e-mail, but lists jobs that aren't marked as allowing remote work anyway.

Comment: It's not just the "allows remote" filter that's being ignored, seems the location filtering is also being ignored, too.  I've updated the question to include an example of this issue also.

Comment: Yup. Got two of those, removed my subscription. Since Careers is going through a major change, they won't likely fix this, as Careers employee says [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312565/custom-url-is-not-being-correctly-generated-in-privacy-settings): "we're declining bugs on careers.stackoverflow unless the are a huge dealbreaker".

Comment: I'm looking at this now. It will be fixed.

Comment: cc @ShadowWizard (this was a huge dealbreaker)

Comment: @Pops just bunch of emails? Well, you decide. :) (personally I'm so used to real spam, that I really don't care for anything I know I can unsubscribe from)

Comment: But we don't want you to unsubscribe. Hence, we're going to fix it.

Comment: That and it's a fairly fundamental feature of a job board, it should be working.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It basically broke the subscriptions feature entirely, at least for those of us who use the filters. It massively decreased the signal-to-noise ratio, transforming the e-mails from a useful alert about something we wanted to know into another daily message that probably isn't worth reading. I'm glad they fixed it. :)

Comment: @reirab of course, I just assumed it's part of integrating the whole Careers into Stack Overflow, i.e. would be fixed as part of the move hence maybe not worth looking into. Glad they fixed it before.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the report Alexey. We introduced a problem with job search about 48 hours ago, and that was the cause of all this. I've reverted the change, so search results and job subscription e-mail contents should be closer to normal now. Sorry for the bug and the annoying e-mails.

Comment: Any reason you keep this on MSE and not migrating to MSO? I've really lost track of what belong where by now, not to mention what bugs will be declined due to the site shutdown and what bug will still be fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard FWIW, the link to report issues from SO Careers is meta.SE, not meta.SO.