# Subscription bug: receiving emails for questions with tags that do not match my filter

Tags: bug, email, subscription

As of yesterday, I've started receiving emails for a subscription that do not match my filter.

**My filter**: [Smalltalk Filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/185552/smalltalk-filter) (shows items with tags [smalltalk](/questions/tagged/smalltalk) or [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) across all StackExchange sites)

**Time of first email**: 14 March 2017 at 10:22 UTC

**Subject of first email**: New questions in Smalltalk Filter filter for Mar 14 - Stack Exchange

**Items in first email**:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776264/how-to-use-r-style-indicator-functions-with-tmb
- [Elixir, Ecto pattern matching conditional with db query not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776078/elixir-ecto-pattern-matching-conditional-with-db-query-not-behaving-as-expected)
- [Optimizing a function in Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774463/optimizing-a-function-in-eigen)

These are in no way related to my filter (tags include [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) and [r](/questions/tagged/r)). I've also checked that none of the tags have a synonym that would explain the issue.

There do not seem to be existing recent questions relating to my topic (the closed one I saw was about [job emails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271463/subscription-bug-emails-including-jobs-that-do-not-match-defined-filters) from a while ago). I thought the first email was a one-off mistake, until I received another email with three more items that don't match that filter today so I thought I'd better report it.

The filter has been working for months if not years - please fix subscription emails, and let me know if any further information or forwarding the emails to someone would be helpful in debugging.

Comment: Me too. Had no time to report it yet. Something funny going on there.

Answer (score 3):

We're aware of a problem here; I am actively investigating. To keep things in one place, I'm going to post updates [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345506/23354).

Comment: I've checked - nothing is missing from my feed, so no mis-direction.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295787/i-stopped-receiving-newsletter-on-my-filter)? someone who doesn't get any emails at all.