# I stopped receiving newsletter on my filter

Tags: support, newsletter, tag-filters

Long ago, I set up a filter to receive web worker and userscript related questions. Check my settings:

[image: image description]

I have received nothing for months as I just realized. I have no problems receiving emails from other sites. What could be wrong? I enjoy answering these kinds of questions so I would really like to be notified when people ask them.

Comment: I see [the filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/146962/web-workers) has some questions going through. I just subscribed to see if I get those emails.

Comment: Most likely related to [this ongoing bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292387/subscription-bug-receiving-emails-for-questions-with-tags-that-do-not-match-my), which isn't solved yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard very unlikely to be related; the change that introduced that is shelved and inactive, pending resources to investigate more which cog fell out

Comment: I just received a notification email for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43870492/1983854).

Comment: @MarcGravell I tried another email and the filter still does not work. What can I do at this point? I think stackexchange itself is losing by not sending me those emails, since I'm quite competen in those areas.